# How to stop Linking error without changing Runtime Library?

Tags: c++, static-linking

Ok so I am new to C++ and I am trying to include libcURL. I have created a static library as opposed to using the DLL as I want to be able to reduce my programs dependencies by as much as possible.
I have also set my Runtime Library in Visual Studio 2012 to MT and MTd as I understand this removes the need for redistributables to be installed?
Anyway, as soon as I add the line `#define CURL_STATICLIB`, MSVCR110.dll & LIBCMTD.lib clash with each other. I understand that this is because MSVCR110.dll is built with /MD and LIBCMTD.lib is built with /MT but I need to use the static library AND have the Runtime set to /MT

**How can I fix the linking error without changing the Runtime Library?** if thats no possible then **How can fix this while keeping zero dependencies for my application?**

Also, If the linking error only concerns MSVCR110.dll & LIBCMTD.lib, then why does it only occur when `#define CURL_STATICLIB` is set, and not all the time?

Thanks

Comment: You are linking code that was compiled with /MT with code that was compiled with /MD.  That cannot work, all code must be compiled with the same setting.  A #define can't get that job done.  Good odds that you just have an incompatible build for curl.